# ideal resolution value for android application

Tags: android

What is the ideal resolution value that can i choose for my android application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not target one screen resolution or size but instead make your application scalable.

A good starting point for figuring out how to do that is here the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation article.

Comment: @bharath - if this answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.